# List of top tags on user profiles says "1 posts" instead of "1 post"

Tags: bug, profile-page, plurals, top-tags

The list of top tags on user profiles says "1 posts" instead of "1 post"

[image: list of top tags, some of which have "1 posts" for their post count]